# jQuery noConflict Redactor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, redactor

I use Prototype JS as main JS library and I have integrate the last RedactorJS with jQuery in mode no conflict but i can't launch function like :

```
jQuery('#redactor').redactor('destroy');
```

OR

```
jQuery('#redactor').destroy();
```

*ERROR : Error: No such method "destroy" for Redactor*

Have you a solution to this problem?

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GM09x3Uv3onpZgPzKKao)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with 9.X :

```
jQuery('#redactor').redactor('getObject').destroy();
```

Tested with 8.X :

```
jQuery('#redactor').redactor('getObject').destroyEditor();
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GM09x3Uv3onpZgPzKKao)

Comment: Thank you @AlexKevler you are not a noob !

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Redactor at all, but after taking a peak at the source code it looks like they store the Redactor object inside of the corresponding jQuery pointers data object. So *I think* you should be able to do the following

```
jQuery('#redactor').data('redactor').destroy();
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: No because lib redactorJS isn't free ;)

Comment: I take it this isn't the correct jQuery wrapper then?
https://github.com/dybskiy/redactor-js

Comment: Check my query, i added a plunker demo.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of callmehiphop gave me the final hint!
Redactor 9 is still broken at this point :( Here's the fix:

```
if (typeof $('#redactor').data('redactor') != 'undefined') {
    // redactor is initialized!
    $('#redactor').destroy();
}
```